# Flutter textformfield

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can I have a new line property in the textfield widget? SO that the text entered when reaches a certain point, it shifts to a new line. Can anyone help me fix this?

Code :

```
body: Center(
      child: Container(
        height: 500,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.black,
              width: 2,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
          child: TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'UserName',
                hintStyle:
                    TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 24.0)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Official Docs, **The maxLines property can be set to null to remove the restriction on the number of lines. By default, it is one, meaning this is a single-line
text field. maxLines must not be zero.**

You just have to add **maxLines: null**

```
body: Center(
      child: Container(
        height: 500,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.black,
              width: 2,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
          child: TextFormField(
            maxLines: null,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'UserName',
                hintStyle:
                    TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 24.0)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```